# A question about coadjoint orbit

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry

If the coadjoint orbit $\Omega\subset \mathfrak{g^*}$ be contractible then prove that $\Omega$ is integral , i.e.,

$\int_C \omega\in \mathbb{Z}$ for every integral singular 2-cycle $C$ in $\Omega$, where $\omega$ is canonical symplectic form on coadjoint orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your coadjoint orbit is contractible, its second cohomology group is trivial; therefore, a symplectic form must be exact... and every exact symplectic manifold is prequantisable.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you... Surely spheres are not contractible?

Comment: I got it all wrong. Let me edit it to a proper answer.